# Trouble with .bmp textures in JOGL

Tags: image, textures, jogl, bmp

I try to set up 3 filters for texture, using JOGL.

```
        File txtr = new File( "Glass_jpeg.jpg" );
        Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture( txtr, true );
        texture = t.getTextureObject();
        //TextureData txData = AWTTextureIO.newTextureData( gl.getGLProfile(), ImageIO.read( txtr ), true );
        TextureData txData = TextureIO.newTextureData( gl.getGLProfile(), txtr, true, null );

        gl.glGenTextures( 3, textures );

        gl.glBindTexture( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.get( 0 ) );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST );
        gl.glTexImage2D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.getWidth(),  t.getWidth(), 0,
                GL2.GL_RGB, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txData.getBuffer() );

        gl.glBindTexture( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.get( 1 ) );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR );
        gl.glTexImage2D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.getWidth(), t.getHeight(), 0,
                GL2.GL_RGB, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txData.getBuffer() );

        gl.glBindTexture( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.get( 2 ) );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
        GLU glu = GLU.createGLU( gl );
        glu.gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, t.getWidth(), t.getHeight(), GL2.GL_RGB,
                GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, txData.getBuffer() );
```

Problem is that my code works properly only if I use TextureIO class and if my image's format is .jpg. When I try to use AWTTextureIO and/or 16, 24, 256 .bmp format, texture flips over and  texture's colors change from red to blue. Explain pls is it possible to use .bmp format correctly in JOGl ?

Comment: You mix calls to higher level methods using JOGL texture API with lower level calls to raw OpenGL methods, it doesn't help. Texture.getMustFlipVertically() probably returns true in your case which means that you have to flip the lines in your own code, I can show you an example if necessary (this is done in some APIs relying on JOGL). Are you sure that you should use GL_RGB here? By the way, JOGL supports GIF, DDS, TGA, JPG, PNG, TIFF, PAM, PPM, ... BMP isn't the "best" choice if you need something lossless.

Comment: I try to repeat NeHe's lessons. That's why i use these parameters in methods.

Comment: You can use these parameters without using lower level calls. Good luck.